# JSTL accessing properties from java bean

Tags: java, jstl

I'm pretty new to JSTL so bear with me. I have a class I created that I'm try to access properties from in JSTL. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm not getting an error I"m just getting nothing when I try to call "getChildPath" Is it something in the java class that I'm doing that I'm not able to access it in the JSTL? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Java Class:

```
public class childPath{

private String childPath = ""; 

public childPath(Resource resource) throws RepositoryException{     
    ValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);     
    childPath = properties.get("childPath", "");                    
}       
public String getChildPath() {
    return childPath;
}
```

My JSTL Reference:

```
${getChildPath}
```

Comment: Hey again Delmon, welcome back! Are you using a Servlet for this project?

Comment: I agree with Kent,it's a great Mess of naming!

Comment: Hey @Jeff I am using a servlet for this project. Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0):

first you should fix your naming to follow java naming convention.

say, you have passed a javabean (type `childPath`) instance (named `bean`)  to your jsp, in your jsp you can reference the attribute `private String childPath` by:

```
${bean.childPath}
```

use the attribute/property name instead of method (getter) name.

Comment: thanks @kent for replying. Sorry I'm a newb but what would be the instance in my code? Is it whatever you name the class so "childPath" sorry I know the naming is a mess.